# Error: Converting circular structure to json. Data received from salesforce with access token

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Following is code I am using to connect Slack with Salesforce to fetch usreInfo.
Everything works fine until I call 'whoami' function. I am receiving a JSON file from salesforce with access token and other details.
I am trying to put that JSON file inside mappings object and fetch the values inside it in the 'whoami' function.

```
  access_token: '00D2x000001eSKboj9MZ_C1cMLV5N823jCiHXl.9WAu2gRQJQ_mtkbGWj3Yd.GvCWncFMYTuMd4AROItvGW6unk8fsxqO',
  signature: '7DGROVVQDt0fqubf6zQdTXSDtFPEezeVsyDk0kg=',
  scope: 'full',
  id_token: 'eyJraWQiOiIyMjIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdF9oYXNoIjoianJZeVc3RUVkZ0VOQ3pramNHdVBPQSIsInN1YiI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4uc2FsZXNmb3JjZS5jb20vaWQvMDBEMngwMDAwMDFlU0tiRUFNLzAwNTJ4MDAwMDAxNlpsREFBVSIsImF1ZCI6IjNNVkc5N3F1QW1GWkpmVnk5JsOFF3aldtck5ZTEJYMzdoenExWXpJcDNEZFNHbVc2YzZiaHc0b3BpSVdQRFVzMVMiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLnNhbGVzZm9yY2UuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTg4MTQzMjMwLCJpYXQiOjE1ODgxNDMxMTB9.WY9ELT5c65p8UeZ3yPRX-Ph8cc-Z2tprY1lCEv1KVos5XfO6qUNQQ_JmTACb-n6fHH3rWZgnceBMD6qlnXeIFvtmVg_MX3oXzfQKmkuo0x0HTp7mSempxcN6vsPIixoOGkOH-v712G3V36t_TU6ZcMn-Pc0xpSKDgEeFL7egqypiNoqXcm_wd_2tNUeLXwiYml80q7MI6SvHn2XVY0xfh6C5ffl2G4bCc8dckEscERa6edeuIrLA4R1x5v4djdK4X2D_TKTTpI4mX_YzuGkZVPaUsgcuk5jMqo2nF8tL37vOvKHI6qlXBUnlUXeJbh6PlfZi7CHi-uwweJQCmOq_69GwThisFHSvuSh9hreVGUmlFDb79qLnAGe5Y5Nm50h-ec6N2v7CN8pjg54tVHe-WfsKKLELkwLe24ZNZTEMLvHGye8iYXkyb-7sRNC9YKYSK_Ubcwev44JlmaShw4NO0GLqgYz5a_1x_Kz6Uc3MdJd7IsmF1AbgNLppmb09wA6s3_Ov871FmdKe8dAFgIr1xJ7LNZHmzNd1b3kHgGleMA8NAwn1GCZV9ItR1vWxZ24X6tZpICTu6pTQVT9PRHJ17zK6RcNfIuW9yXfM-xO2z7nBu1E2zBtm7ulPNSemUY9edeD5Nf1mnsNtTGiOMHkcMoaIHryrkbZ5YTGPJmlBm3c',
  instance_url: 'https://ap17.salesforce.com',
  id: 'https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D2x00000SKbEAM/0050000016ZlDAAU',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  issued_at: '1588143490'
}
```

Above is the access token string i am receiving from the salesforce.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var url = require('url');
var clientId = 'hidde ';
var clientSecret = 'hidden';
var SF_LOGIN_URL = "https://login.salesforce.com";
var SF_CLIENT_ID = "hidden";
var SF_CLIENT_SECRET = "hidden";
var SF_AUTH_CODE;
var SF_ACCESS_TOKEN;
var SF_ACCESS_TOKEN_1;
var SF_DOMAIN;
var slackUserId;
var mappings = {};
// We define the port we want to listen to. Logically this has to be the same port than we specified on ngrok.
const PORT=4390;

// Instantiates Express and assigns our app variable to it
var app = express();
app.enable('trust proxy');

//var server = http.createServer(app);
//Lets start our server
app.listen(PORT, function () {
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening.
    console.log("Example app listening on port " + PORT);
});

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

// Route the endpoint that our slash command will point to and send back a simple response to indicate that ngrok is working
app.post('/oauth', function(req, res) {
    oauth(req, res);
    slackUserId = req.body.user_id;
});

app.get('/oauth', function(req, res) {

// console.log(req.query.state);
oauth_access(req, res);
    SF_AUTH_CODE = req.query.code;
});

app.post('/whoami', function(req, res){
    console.log("Inside whoami");
    if(slackUserId === req.body.user_id){
        console.log("Crossed user ID");
            userInfo();
            res.send(req);
        }
});

function oauth(req, res){
    res.redirect(200, `${SF_LOGIN_URL}/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${SF_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=https://hidden.ngrok.io/oauth&display=touch}`);
}
function oauth_access(req, res){
    res.redirect(200, `${SF_LOGIN_URL}/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${SF_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=https://hidden.ngrok.io/oauth&display=touch}`);
}

function oauth_access(req, res){
    let options = {
        url: `${SF_LOGIN_URL}/services/oauth2/token`,
        qs: {
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            code: req.query.code,
            client_id: SF_CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: SF_CLIENT_SECRET,
            redirect_uri: `https://hidden.ngrok.io/oauth`
        }
    };

    request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.send("error");
        }
        //Storing the body consisting of access token to the mappings
        // SF_ACCESS_TOKEN = mappings[slackUserId].access_token;
        //Accessing the access token supplied by the SF
        // console.log(mappings[slackUserId].access_token);
        let html = `
            <html>
            <body style="text-align:center;padding-top:100px">
            <img src="/images/linked.png"/>
            <div style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue';font-weight:300;color:#444">
                <h2 style="font-weight: normal">Authentication completed</h2>
                Your Slack User Id is now linked to your Salesforce User Id.<br/>
                You can now go back to Slack and execute authenticated Salesforce commands.
            </h2>
            </body>
            </html>
            `;
        res.send(html);
        //body is in JSON format so we will try to store it inside global JSON object and access it through out the script!
        // slackUserId_value = slackUserId.toString();
        // console.log(slackUserId_value);
        console.log(typeof(body));
        // mappings[slackUserId].body = undefined;
        mappings[slackUserId] = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(typeof(mappings));
        console.log(mappings[slackUserId]);

        // console.log(mappings);
        // access_token_string = "access_token";
        // console.log(mappings[slackUserId]);
        console.log(mappings[slackUserId].access_token);
        SF_ACCESS_TOKEN = mappings[slackUserId].access_token;
        //SF_ACCESS_TOKEN_1 = SF_ACCESS_TOKEN;
    });
};

function userInfo(){
    console.log("User Info Function");
    // SF_ACCESS_TOKEN = mappings[slackUserId].access_token;
    mappings[slackUserId].access_token = undefined;

    //console.log(mappings[slackUserId].access_token);


    let options = {
        url: `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo`,
        qs: {
            oauth_token: SF_ACCESS_TOKEN,
            redirect_uri: `https://hidden.ngrok.io/whoami`
        }
    };
    request.post(options, function(error, response, body){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            return res.send("error");
        }
    });
};
```

Following is the output:

```
string
object
{
  access_token: '00D2x000001eSKb!ARwAv1AWvtCd1.xew2dqgscgNfryydnpPlWbTrC7eQEw0ViEb1v7SWbwcMDHOHiyWQ6a0y9DFJ56.ldKDGfoG',
  signature: 'lXynNIOCEF6Qz5m4qsG8dCfucwNmEkx5YeEKRH0=',
  scope: 'full',
  id_token: 'eyJraWQiOiIyMjIiLCJ0eXAiOiciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdF9oYXNoIjoiR1dPdi0xTzJnZl91WnFidkFVOEtYZyIsInN1YiI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4uc2FsZXNmb3JjZS5jb20vaWQvMDBEMngwMDAwMDFlU0tiRUFNLzAwNTJ4MDAwMDAxNlpsREFBVSIsImF1ZCI6IjNNVkc5N3F1QW1GWkpmVnk5Mjk5MEgxaS5uaW1nRkRyREZockJsOFF3aldtck5ZTEJYMzdoenExWXpJcDNEZFNHbVc2YzZiaHc0b3BpSVdQRFVzMVMiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLnNhbGVzZm9yY2UuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTg4MTQzNzEyLCJpYXQiOjE1ODgxNDM1OTJ9.aI-wxVy2KLo9GDQDjxffdaZv8BmdftUQkWtI8kpXby8h-iLvNRDLSY4KrDQwJgAQAB2HUUaabftc2u-FeLh99h5Zuu4SGiyGZVPsPZ0Fkf0SjAcLiR4Q9caaYCwvlCkK_PM_v0IqWO413kXkcw2wEqvko-ekOM0bss26Qpiti0pcJntcMBn7XyIiAHhA7Fx5AhF9VnNyJIbI9cIIOFHtY_CoQsBgl-HmM7aYY5zXCUSdjbm4a4hNzV1veE4DL5Oxp5gto3vhRLd198koIaDA3xaIf_nyal6PEcafHfdQ3QlrNnSpigrKkB5Y5-vwY1xLf0EwkQ2bcOzT7l7fPsV1CN4PY3vjUyj1_tgpR_RJMTApM2etTbB1nMFxwTAnTwctVuZfK5fZeTp04XlZOpAyysAUaS9_1uhb6fLn-8CHW3tcPTT0cMqmJ0OgB5Tio_TGNRHb-xbWXxkFHXuatX2Lwj94xo_RfbT4CPYfK9JGQvsyPy8clclwsn-KLW8lx7tYYl2pEQthz9UX14WmgAQ2PzrVgEcTvf-kG4oORZsBvNraBcZVrYSdGUxaicjfoYA3Ue1sXIhyW_TvvRqsgWcXzhO-Qz2DuT6TTxb0tC6zlfvjeShhvnlLcukUfeyZPbuSksALD-ApLEQwAx8AzKZlmQ6N0dj7-CDcmGoG_4f493k',
  instance_url: 'https://ap17.salesforce.com',
  id: 'https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D2x01eSKbEAM/0052x0000lDAAU',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  issued_at: '15881435266'
}
00D2x000001eSKb!ARwAQMguUkqgscgNfryydnpPlWbTrC7eQEw0ViEb1v7SWbwcMDHOHiyWQ6a0y9DFJ56.ldKDGfoG
Inside whoami
Crossed user ID
User Info Function
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (/Users/sonagrasumit/Desktop/salckapp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/sonagrasumit/Desktop/salckapp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/sonagrasumit/Desktop/salckapp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at /Users/sonagrasumit/Desktop/salckapp/index.js:51:17
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/sonagrasumit/Desktop/salckapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/sonagrasumit/Desktop/salckapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/sonagrasumit/Desktop/salckapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/sonagrasumit/Desktop/salckapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/sonagrasumit/Desktop/salckapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
```

I have modified credentials for security reasons.

Comment: Where and what exactly is the problem?  You said you received some data from salesforce so that apparently isn't the data with a circular problem.  What data has a circular problem?  The `access_token` property in your first data block is just a string so it's hard to see how that causes any sort of circular problem.

Comment: updated please check

Comment: Found the solution:
Change the location of app.post('/whoami'....){...} request to just before userInfo function.